# Groovy: Unable to read a json file from jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have to read some input from report.json file which is in the jenkins workspace. I am using the following code to read the file but it says file not found error. I am running this script on Groovy Postbuild step.

```
import hudson.model.*
 
def fileContents = new File('C:\\jenkinstest_slave\\workspace\\Cypress\\mochawesome-report\\report.json').readLines()    
def result = fileContents.findAll { it.contains('passPercent') }
manager.listener.logger.println("matching word from findAll method= " +result)
```

Error:

```
Groovy script failed:
java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Is the file in the Workspace of the current Job or in a different location? Also, where are you executing this script?

Comment: This file is in the workspace of the current job and I am executing this script in Grooy Postbuild plugin.

Comment: have you tried using the WORKSPACE env variable instead of the fully qualified path?

Comment: i think postbuild executed on master and not on slaves